# Jquery on click does not work when code changes in safari 9.0.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I have come across a wierd situation where i am unable to fire event in Safari using Jquery on click. The thing is for example: i bind on click to a button and alert hello. First time it works. Now i changed the code in js and say something like alert Jello. Now , it only fires the hello, the old code that i wrote. It is not taking my new changed code which should have alerted Jello. Again, when i changed the id of the button and try again, it wokrs the first time and alerts Jello, after that it's old same.

Note that i have tested this same in firefox but no issues, it gets the changes. also i tried with document and window load but no luck. What do you think of this problem ? Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're getting a cached version of the javascript being brought back. Try a refresh and clear the cache by using one of the following (depending on whether your on a mac or not):

- Hold the Ctrl key and press the F5 key.
- Hold the ⇧ Shift key and click the Reload button on the navigation
  toolbar.
- Hold the Ctrl key and click the Reload button on the navigation
  toolbar.
- Hold the ⇧ Shift key and press the F5 key.

[Wikipedia Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)